# Forum creation with bbpress and front end

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, bbpress

I'm completely new to blogging and having real trouble setting up a forum where users can private message each other. I've done some research online and decided to download bbpress and front end PM, what I've ended up with is not what I expected. There are a few things that I would like to change.

Firstly, the two plugins aren't synced. I want a user to be able to see a post or reply on the forum and for there to be a message link either on the post/reply so they can contact that user, or if they click on the users profile, for there to be a message option there. I can't seem to do that?

Secondly, when someone registers to the forum they end up at this log in page.

[image]

Once registered, they then have access to a dashboard (similar to an admin one)

[image]

The create password email they receive is also from WordPress. This is not what I was expecting and definitely not what I want. I have never experienced anything like this while joining forums in other websites. How do I make it *normal*?

As I mentioned at the top of this post, I'm new to blogging, so please make your response simple because I wont understand advanced terminology :)

Answer (score 0):

bbPress is a plugin for WordPress, and it completley integrates in WordPress: forum users and WordPress website users, forum uses WordPress for a lot of things, including login, and forum users get basic access to admin side (only own profile, like all WP users). You can create pages to use forum form for login and registration, use forum widgets, but that is not done automatically, you need to do it.

And, finally, bbPress doesn't have private messages system at all. There are plugins for that, and you can try and find some on WordPress.org

Comment: Thanks Milan, so your saying if I don't want them to be able to access a Wordpress dashboard I need to use a plug in that is not fully interpreted with Wordpress?

Comment: No, there are ways to disable access to admin side - other plugins or some custom code. Most things in WP are done with plugins and almost everything can be modified.